# how to form action with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert information from the form to the Database.
This is the form in html - tried both post and get.

```
<form id="register" action="script/register.js" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
<br>
<label for="passd">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="passd" id="passd" placeholder="Password" />
<br>
<label for="conpassd">Password:</label>
<input type ="password" name="conpassd" id="conpassd" placeholder="re-type Password"/>
<br>
<label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address"/>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submitMe" id="submitMe">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>
```

This is the script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var usernameCorrect = false;
    var passwordCorrect = false;

    function checkPassword() {
        var p1 = $("#passd").val();
        var p2 = $("#conpassd").val();
        if(p1 == p2) {
            passwordCorrect = true;
        } else {
            passwordCorrect = false;
            alert("Passwords does not match");
        }
    }

    function checkUsername() {
        var user = $("#username").val();
        var dataPass = {
            "username": user
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "server/userExists.cgi",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            data: dataPass,
            success: function(data) {
                var user = $.trim(data);
                if(user == "No") {
                    usernameCorrect = true;
                } else if(user == "Yes") {
                    usernameCorrect = false;
                    alert("Username already in use");
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Script Execution Error');
            },
        });
    }

    function submitForm() {
        if(usernameCorrect == true && passwordCorrect == true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataPass = {
                'username': (username),
                'passd': ($("#passd").val()),
                'email': ($("#conpassd").val())
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "server/init.cgi",
                type: "GET",
                data: dataPass,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Register successful");
                    //nextPage(username);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error!");
                },
            });
        }
    }

    $("#submitMe").click(function(e) {
        submitForm();
    });

});
```

Is there anyway to link the form to javascript? I don't know any other language such as php so...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors

- Your form points to a JavaScript file, it should point to the server cgi script.
- You're never calling `checkUsername()` and `checkPassword()` so `usernameCorrect` and `passwordCorrect` are still false.
- You're hooking to the button's click event, the better event is the form's submit since it also fires when they hit enter in the form and you can cancel a submit and send an AJAX request instead, this way, your form also works if JavaScript is off.

Here's what you need to change, Your HTML for the form should be

```
<form id="register" action="server/init.cgi" method="post">
```

And your script had to be adjusted slightly because of the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls, you have to use callbacks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#register').on('submit', function(e){
        // so the form doesn't get sent since we are going to send it with AJAX
        e.preventDefault();

        var user = $("#username").val(), 
            pwd = $("#passd").val(), 
            pwd2 = $("#conpassd").val(),
            form = this;

        if (pwd != pwd2) {
            alert("Passwords does not match");
            return false;
        }
        var dataPass = {"username": user};
        $.ajax({
            url: "server/userExists.cgi",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            data: dataPass,
            success: function(data) {
                var user = $.trim(data);
                    if(user == "Yes") {
                       alert("Username already in use");
                       return;
                    }
                    else {
                        submitForm();
                    }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Script Execution Error');
            },
        });

        function submitForm() {
            var dataPass = {'username': user,'passd': pwd,'email': ($('#email').val())};
            $.ajax({
                // no need to duplicate the URL here, the form already knows it
                url: form.action,
                type: "GET",
                data: dataPass,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Register successful");
                    //nextPage(username);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error!");
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any `action` on the form - and just add the `.js` file normally, using a `<script>` element.

```
<form id="register" method="post">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/register.js"></script>
```

You are already attaching to the submit button click event in the script and it calls your ajax routine, so no need for anything more.

You also need to override the default behaviour of the form by attaching to the submit event of the form and return `false;` from the function in order to not actually post the form.

Comment: I have loaded the register.js in the <head> and just tried and it said method post not allowed...

Comment: @CorsadiTempo - Not something that can be guessed from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The `action="script/register.js"` means you are submitting your form data to a URI like this:
http://example.com/script/register.js

you'll probably want the submit-action to trigger a javascript function. Like this:

```
<form onsubmit="someJsFunction(); return false;" action="some/uri.cgi" >...</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change following things.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/register.js"></script>

<form id="register" method="post" action="sample.cgi">
```

Here sample.cgi is your required action page.

You need to add action on form